# Multiple File Upload in Google App Engine / Java works in Development Machine but not when Deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

This is part of my servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);

    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iterator;

    try {
        iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        Picture pic = null;
        PictureAccess access = null;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next(); 

            pic = new Picture( blobs.get(item.getFieldName()).getKeyString() );

            access = new PictureAccess();
            access.addPictures(pic, user.getEmail() );
        }

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    res.sendRedirect("/user/picture/upload.jsp");
}
```

In my client side, I used JavaScript to change the names of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function uploadFile() {
        if (window.File && window.FileList) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;
            for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fd.append("file" + i, files[i]);
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", document.getElementById('uploadForm').action);
            xhr.send(fd);

            alert('already saved');
            document.getElementById('uploadForm').value = '';

        } else {
            document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit(); //no html5
        }
    }

</script>
```

In my html/jsp:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/user/uploadPics") %>">
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple" size="5"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

The above codes works in development machine but not working when deployed. What are the possible error and solution to the problem? How can I see the error in appengine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated method `getUploadedBlobs(..)` [does not support `multiple='true'`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#getUploadedBlobs%28HttpServletRequest%29). Try using [`getUploads(..)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#getUploads%28HttpServletRequest%29) instead.

Comment: thanks. this works Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);